# Generate SHA1 using online SHA1 conversion tool from PowerShell script

Tags: rest, powershell, sha1

I have a PowerShell script that needs to access an online SHA1 conversion tool and generate a hash.

I used Fiddler to try and see what the call looks like when running the online tool with valid params, but my calls fail.

Here is my call:

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator/formconvert/ -Body @{"hash_string" = $forClientHash}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to query the online service?  PowerShell is perfectly capable of [generating an SHA1 hash](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-StringHash-aa843f71).

Comment: Not to mention that [SHA-1 is broken](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html) and should be avoided.

Comment: haha. yes i know about the fact that sha-1 is broken , but i am playing with some web api calls that use sha1